# generate sound from integers in c#

Tags: c#, integer, soundcard

I want to generate sound for integers like tones for integers 1 to 10 and then send that to sound card.
For example a 440 Hz tone for 1
500 Hz to 2
600 Hz for 3 and so on...
Frequency is not the matter. The problem is generation of tone for many integers and then saving these tones into  a .wave file and then playing that wave file.

Comment: That sounds like a great goal. [So, what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: i m just a beginner dont know much regarding that

Comment: @user2178661 Then it seems like this is a good learning opportunity for you.  If you just have other people do your work for you then you won't learn, and you'll be a beginner for the rest of your life.  If you spend time solving your own problems you can become an expert yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to set the frequency = the existing music standard.

```
var a = Math.Pow(2.0, 1.0/12.0);
var b = // Your Integer Here;

var f = 440 * Math.Pow(a, b);
```

That will give you the frequency of the chromatic scale. If you want a major scale, you can use `b = 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, or 12`

Link to the formula for musical notes: http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/NoteFreqCalcs.html